# In Perl, how can I check if a file is locked?

Tags: perl

How exactly would I check to see if a file is locked exclusively? I have this function but it is returning 1 no matter what I do:

```
sub is_file_locked
{
  my $theFile;
  my $theRC;

  ($theFile) = @_;
  $theRC = open(HANDLE, $theFile);
  $theRC = flock(HANDLE, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB);
  close(HANDLE);
  return !$theRC;
}
```

Comment: 12 questions and no accepted answers :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have opened `$theFile` in read mode and `LOCK_EX` [isn't meant to be used that way](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#flock).

> Note that the fcntl(2) emulation of flock(3) requires that
>   FILEHANDLE be open with read intent to use LOCK_SH and requires
>   that it be open with write intent to use LOCK_EX.

Answer (score 7):

First off, you should check if `open` succeeded.

Also, you should check if you can get a shared lock. `flock` with `LOCK_EX` would (I think) fail, if there is a shared lock on the file.

However, the file can become locked between the check and the return, creating a race condition, so such a function is of dubious value.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Fcntl qw( :flock );

print is_locked_ex($0)
      ? "$0 : locked exclusively\n"
      : "$0 : not locked exclusively\n";

my $test_file = 'test.txt';
open my $fh, '>', $test_file
    or die "Cannot open '$test_file' for writing: $!";

if ( flock $fh, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB ) {
    print is_locked_ex($test_file)
          ? "$test_file : locked exclusively\n"
          : "$test_file : not locked exclusively\n";
}

close $fh or die "Cannot close '$test_file': $!";

sub is_locked_ex {
    my ($path) = @_;

    die "Not a plain file: '$path'" unless -f $path;
    return 1 unless open my $fh, '<', $path;

    my $ret = not flock $fh, LOCK_SH | LOCK_NB;
    close $fh
        or die "Cannot close '$path': $!";

    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: Alright I got it! I posted my solution at the bottom. You are correct about the "However, the file can become locked between the check and the return, creating a race condition, so such a function is of dubious value." a perfect solution seems impossible at this day in age.

Comment: I was using this code, and it works 99% of the time, but I had to keep a double check using redis to make sure I was locked exclusive. I did some tests and it's safe to use IO::LockedFile with block => 0 to really lock 100% of the time or fail. Here is a test script to verify https://gist.github.com/renatocron/7dae3e3e33f94b8afd353858f82ad7d3

Answer (score -2):

The final solution:

```
flock($fh, LOCK_EX) or die "Cannot lock file - $!\n";

if ( is_file_locked($gTestQueuePath) ){ print "locked";} else { print "not locked";}

#1 = locked 0 = not locked
sub is_file_locked
{
  my $theFile;
  my $theRC;

  ($theFile) = @_;
  $theRC = open(my $HANDLE, ">>", $theFile);
  $theRC = flock($HANDLE, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB);
  close($HANDLE);
  return !$theRC;
}

close $fh or die "Cannot close";
```